# Apportable and iOS Accelerate framework

Tags: android, ios, frameworks, apportable

Does Apportable support this framework?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html

I am trying to build the sample project for an Audio Unit wrapper as AVAudioPlayer is too slow on Android for me:
https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine

I added it as a dependency but it doesn't seem to be able to find it. If not are there any work arounds to get novocaine working with Apportable? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apportable doesn't currently support Accelerate.  That is a very large, special purpose framework that we haven't heard many people requesting.

Novocaine definitely uses Accelerate, so at this point, that library won't work.  Our initial CoreAudio and AudioUnit support is written without Accelerate, so if you can use those directly to solve your needs, you may be able to get it working.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That is too bad. I have looked at samples for CoreAudio and it is very daunting as I dont know C very well. Do you know any other wrappers I could use or possibly some sample tutorial to play an mp3? My game works perfectly with AVAudioPlayer but it seems the currentTime property is not updated quick enough with the Android equivalent. This is the only thing preventing my game from being playable unfortunately :( Definitely considering the Indie version if I can get this solved as I would love to implement ads/in-app purchase!